# Exclude file content from logs in spring-ws

Tags: logging, spring-ws

on project we use spring-ws and their logging of incoming requests and responses. Everything works fine except that to request we attach files. In the logs we also see content of these files. Is there some easy way to exclude them? Do we need to implement custom logging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have `TRACE` level debugging enabled on the `org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing` logger, correct? That prints out the entire message, including any attachments.

If you don't want to print the attachments, you can disable the `MessageTracing` logger and use the [SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/api/org/springframework/ws/soap/server/endpoint/interceptor/SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor.html) instead.

Comment: But SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor logs only server requests, right? What I need is logging client messages. That would probably mean using custom ClientIntercepter?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know this was client-side. In that case, you'll probably have to write your own `ClientInterceptor`, correct. You can take inspiration from that `SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor`, though.